# Adding Data-Bind to Bootrstrap Dropdown

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I am trying to pull in a list of values through data-bind into a Twitter Bootstrap dropdown.

```
<div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Action <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" data-bind="options: artists, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value:selectedArtistId">
            <li></li>
          </ul>
</div>
```

I came across Knockout_bootstrap JS but am not sure it works with drop downs

http://billpull.github.io/knockout-bootstrap/

(no example provided)

Answer (score 3):

**HTML List vs HTML Select**
The bootstrap dropdown is an html list.

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

The knockout js [`options` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) is a binding for html `select` elements.

```
<select>
   <option></option>
</select>
```

I cannot tell for sure what you *want* to do, but what you are currently doing is adding the knockout options binding to a `<ul>`, when the binding is supposed to be for a `<select>`.

**Live Example in JS Bin**
Here is an exmaple in jsbin that uses knockout for binding in both scenarios.

http://jsbin.com/ITOZUPI/1/edit

**part of HTML with ko data-bindings**

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Action <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" data-bind="foreach: my.VM.Artists">
    <li><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-bind="text: artistName, click: getTheArtist"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

  <p>&nbsp;</p>

  <select data-bind="options: my.VM.Artists, 
                 optionsCaption: 'Please select an Artist...',  
                 optionsText: 'artistName', 
                 optionsValue: 'artistId',
                 value: my.VM.artist_selected"></select>
```